# Auto-Complete stops working with C files

Tags: completion, yasnippet, auto-complete-mode

I am using Emacs24, and my auto-complete plugin was working when I opened my `.emacs` file. However, it doesn't work when I open some file like :

`whatever.c`

To add to this, the auto-complete-c-headers do not work. I believe that auto-complete doesn't work on c/c++ mode.

Here is my `.emacs` file:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/neotree")
(require 'neotree)
(global-set-key [f8] 'neotree-toggle)

(defun my:ac-c-header-init()
    (require 'auto-complete-c-headers)
    (add-to-list 'ac-sources 'ac-source-c-header))
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'my:a-c-header-init)
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'my:ac-c-header-init)

(require 'cc-mode)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.h\\'" . c++-mode))

(setq-default c-basic-offset 2 c-default-style "linux")
(setq-default tab-width 2 indent-tabs-mode t)
(define-key c-mode-base-map (kbd "RET") 'newline-and-indent)

(add-to-list 'load-path
              "~/.emacs.d/plugins/yasnippet")
(require 'yasnippet)
(yas-global-mode 1)

(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa")
(require 'linum)
(global-linum-mode 1)

(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/auto-complete-1.3.1")
(require 'auto-complete)
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(define-globalized-minor-mode real-global-auto-complete-mode
  auto-complete-mode (lambda ()
                       (if (not (minibufferp (current-buffer)))
                         (auto-complete-mode 1))
                       ))
(real-global-auto-complete-mode t)
(ac-config-default)
(ac-set-trigger-key "TAB")
(ac-set-trigger-key "<tab>")
```

Comment: I figure it out just right now I've edited thanks for your attention

Comment: @VivianMaya, can you post the answer/solution to your problem? Just make an answer that says "Adding the line of code... Solved my problem...". :)

Comment: I did it thanks, I'm a kind of newbie around here.

Comment: No problem. We all have to start somewhere. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I added the following code to solve most of my problem:

```
(setq ac-source-yasnippet nil)
```

But, it caused complexity between yasnippet and auto-complete so I added this:

```
(define-key yas-minor-mode-map (kbd "<tab>") nil)
(define-key yas-minor-mode-map (kbd "TAB") nil)
(define-key yas-minor-mode-map (kbd "<backtab>") 'yas-expand)
```

Modified some keys:

```
(ac-set-trigger-key "TAB")
(ac-set-trigger-key "<tab>")
```

And solved all of my problems.